# .Net Core - Repository Pattern for Multiple Backend Systems

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am creating a .Net Core API with multiple layers

Customer.API

Customer.Business

CustomerService

Customer.Libs

This API has to call 2 Database Systems at this moment (same updates should go to both the systems) and in near future one of the Systems will be decommissioned.

1. DynamoDB
2. SQL Server

I created the repository layer like below and would like to know if this is the correct approach.

Create an abstraction layer and have classes like this in Customer.Libs

MultiDbBaseRepository.cs

SQlServerBaseRepository.cs

MultiDbBaseRepository => This class will call both repository classes SQLDatabaseRespository and DynamoDbRepository
SQlServerBaseRepository => This class will call SQLDatabaseRespository.

Add Dependency to MultiDbRepository in Startup.cs at this moment or drive this instantiation based on some settings, to avoid code deployments in future.

AddScoped<ICustomerBaseRespository, MultiDbBaseRepository >

So, Service layer uses ICustomerBaseRespository and at this moment application will call MultiDbBaseRepository and the changes get updated to both SQL and Dynamodb and if the Startup is changed in future then the application will call the necessary Database.

Can you please let me know if I am violating design pattern?

Comment: My suggestion is to have one dedicated repository for SQL server and one dedicated repository for dynamo DB interaction i.e. as you mentioned `SQLDatabaseRespository` and `DynamoDbRepository` and then wrap the code that has to work with both  `SQLDatabaseRespository` and `DynamoDbRepository` in some business service/helper class which you will register and inject through DI and after that use in your controllers.

Comment: Hi @AntonKovachev, Thanks for your comments. Yes, I pretty much follow the same approach as you mentioned. I wrapped the functionality of SQLDatabaseRespository and DynamoDbRepository under MultiDbBaseRepository and inject this class in the StartUp.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This API has to call 2 Database Systems at this moment (same updates should go to both the systems) and in near future one of the Systems will be decommissioned.

This is almost exactly the scenario I cover in my video [Composite as Universal Abstraction](https://cleancoders.com/episode/humane-code-real-episode-2). In short, you can use the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern for this (and many other) scenarios.

I'm guessing from some of the class names that the repository should deal with customers, so perhaps something like this makes sense:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    void Insert(Customer customer);
    void Update(Customer customer);
    // More members like this..?
}
```

You can now define a `CompositeCustomerRepository` like this:

```
public class CompositeCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly repositories;

    public CompositeCustomerRepository(params ICustomerRepository[] repositories)
    {
        this.repositories = repositories;
    }

    void Insert(Customer customer)
    {
        foreach (var repo in repositories)
            repo.Insert(customer);
    }

    void Update(Customer customer)
    {
        foreach (var repo in repositories)
            repo.Update(customer);
    }
}
```

You'll also have to implement the `ICustomerRepository` interface in two other classes that talk to the two database systems in question:

```
public class DynamoDBCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository { /*...*/ }
public class SqlServerCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository { /*...*/ }
```

Now compose a repository from particular implementations:

```
ICustomerRepository repo = new CompositeCustomerRepository(sqlRepo, dynamoRepo);
```

All clients should talk to the `ICustomerRepository` interface instead of concrete types. Clients will be unaware that they are talking to a Composite rather than a single database. This'll make it trivial to later decomission one of them.

As I cover in my video, if your repository also needs to *read* entities from the database, you'll have to decide from which database you're going to return data. One option is to pick the first non-null result you can find. I also cover that in my video, as well as in my article [Coalescing Composite as a monoid](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/04/09/coalescing-composite-as-a-monoid).

Comment: Thank you @Mark Seemann for your detailed answer. I am able to follow the implementation which have explained. I will work on that.